# nontrivial solution of $\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} -4a \frac{dy}{dx} + 3y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $N$ be a positive integer. Find all real numbers $a$ such that the differential equation $\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} -4a \frac{dy}{dx} + 3y = 0$ has a nontrivial solution satisfying the conditions $y(0) = 0$ and $y(2N\pi) = 0$.

So the characteristic equation will be $m^2 -4am + 3 = 0$. Solving this we get $m = \frac{4a \pm \sqrt{16a^2-12}}{2} = 2a \pm \sqrt{4a^2 - 3}$. So general solution will be of the form $y(x) = c_1 e^{m_1 x} + c_2 e^{m_2 x}$. Plugging in the initial conditions we get $c_1 + c_2 = 0 \implies c_1 = -c_2$ and $c_1e^{m_1 2N\pi} + c_2 e^{m_2 2N\pi} = 0$. Using $c_1 = -c_2$ we get $c_1(e^{m_1 2N\pi} - e^{m_2 2N\pi}) = 0 \implies e^{(m_1-m_2)2N\pi} = 1$ (since $c_1 = 0$ will give trivial solution). $\implies e^{4N\pi \sqrt{4a^2 -3}} =1$. So if $4a^2 > 3$ we must have $N = 0$, a contradiction. If $4a^2 = 3$ we have $a= \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. And if $4a^2 < 3$ we must have $e^{4iN\pi \sqrt{3-4a^2}} =1 \implies \sin(4N\pi \sqrt{3-4a^2}) = 0 \implies 2N \sqrt{3-4a^2}$ must be an integer.

Comment: Do you know the general form of a solution to a second order linear ODE?

Comment: Yes, it is of the form $c_1 e^{m_1 x} + c_2 e^{m_2 x}$.

Comment: So try plugging in the solutions of the characteristic quadratic for the $m$ values. Using your initial conditions, you may solve for $c_1,c_2$ using the resulting system of equations.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Note that your solutions can be complex as well. So split your answer between real solutions and complex solutions. Use $e^{i\phi}=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$

Answer (score 1):

You found that $$e^{(m_2-m_1)2N\pi}=1$$
If we go one step further, $$e^{4\sqrt{4a^2-3}N\pi}=1$$
You need to consider complex solutions as well:
$$e^{2\pi k i}=1$$
for any $k\in\mathbb Z$. The $k=0$ is the solution you already found.So you have $$4a^2-3\le 0$$
and $$2N\sqrt{3-4a^2}\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction. I was just editing my answer.

Comment: So from here, $$a=\pm\frac12\sqrt{3-\frac k{2N}}, k\in \mathbb Z, k\le 6N$$